# Revision history with firebase real time database

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm the working on an [online ide editor for students - codiva.io](https://www.codiva.io) 
I'm planning to support collaboration and revision history, i see that firebase real time database would be great fit for this use case.
Collaboration seems easy, but I couldn't find much info on whether firebase automatically maintains the revision history or if this has to be implemented separately.
I assume firebase uses diffs to sync between devices and probably use operational transformation for resolving conflicts. 
Is it possible to capture the diffs and store separately so that I can support a consistent revision history.

Comment: I believe this [other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36104789/firebase-how-to-efficiently-track-user-record-change-history) might help you...